# Unable to send the data in chunked to the browser

Tags: php

I have a script and trying to send the data in chunked.
For that purpose i disabled output_buffering in php.ini

```
output_buffering=off
```

now when i run my script:

```
echo "stream1";
sleep(5);
echo "stream2";
```

It display the whole output after full execution of script , instead of sending stream1 first and then stream2 after 5 seconds of wait to the browser.

Comment: I am mot a PHP developer, but it make sense. It's a backend script, it works on a server and the way it works is that script is executed and results are sent to the client. If you want to send your data 'one by one' you need your client to send request to the server and your script should send a new portion of data in response to your request.

Comment: 1. you need to `flush()` to actually send output and 2. you have no guarantee that a browser actually decides to immediately show everything received.

Comment: as you suggested i tried echo "stream1"; flush(); but it still showing stream1stream2 together.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
<?PHP
ob_start();

echo 'Output one.';
ob_flush();
sleep(5);
echo 'Output two.';
ob_flush();
?>
```

I think it is more a http request/response issue. On the command line, script works fine.

Normally the response is prepared completely and send to the client. If your response has such a size that multiple tcp packages have to be send, it could happen that the first packages are send, before you script is ready with processing. So it depends on the size of the output. Depending on the client/web browser, it could also happen that the first packages get rendered, before the complete response arrives at the client.

Try below script :

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush(1);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $randSlp=rand(1,3);
    echo "Sleeping for ".$randSlp." second. ";;
    sleep(1);
    if(ob_get_level()>0)
       ob_end_flush(); 
}
```

Comment: but first please tell me should i enable output_buffering in php.ini before trying your script.